# Why do I get an error when adding a category programmatically in Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to write a script that imports my categories from a XML into prestashop. There is one problem, the script does not add the category and stops working when it reaches ->add();

I'm trying to find the problem, but I really don't know what to do anymore.

Here is my script:

```
if ($cat == "") {
        $category = new Category;
        $category->active = 1;
        $category->id_parent = 3;
        $category->name[1] = $product->category_name;;
        $category->link_rewrite[1] = Tools::link_rewrite($product_xml->category_name);
        echo "<br />name of new category = $product->category_name <br /> <br />";
        $category->add();
        $G_array[] = $category->id;
        $G_cat = $G_cat . "\r\n" . 'Category: ' . $category->name[1].' with the id: '.$category->id.' Created'; //adding new category to var, to be displayed at the index page.
    }else{
```

I am using prestashop 1.6, I hope that someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong..

Comment: When you say the script stops working, there's an error message displayed ? could you past your apache error log file ?

Comment: There is no error, anywhere, if I look at my page source there is no weird hidden error message anywhere... I also put error log and error display on. Put dev mode on, nothing helped. /var/log/apache2/error.log is empty.. Any ideas?

Comment: You might have forgotten a "die()" statement somewhere when you where debugging on your previous question ?

Comment: If there's no error displayed you'll have to debug "by hand" or with a debugger like `xdebug` to see what's going on.

Comment: I have found my problem for error reporting, I had it defined twice in my file, so I get my errors now! The biggest error is:  Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /home/ubuntu/workspace/classes/Tools.php on line 1394 Call Stack: 0.0013 236184 Thanks for helping me out by the way :)

Comment: is `$product_xml->category_name` exists? above you use just `$product`

Comment: Yes it did. Im still not awaere what the problem was, but it works now. (switched host, maybe that was a point, very weird) Thanks for all the help and suggestions all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me

```
$Category = new Category();
$Category->name = [(int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => 'nome'];
$Category->link_rewrite = [(int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => 'link_rewrite'];
$Category->description = [(int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => 'descrizione'];
$Category->active = 1;
$Category->id_parent = 3;
$Category->add();
```

for update

```
$Category = new Category($id_category);
$Category->name = [(int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => 'nome'];
$Category->link_rewrite = [(int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => 'link_rewrite'];
$Category->description = [(int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => 'descrizione'];
$Category->active = 1;
$Category->id_parent = 3;
$Category->update();
```

you can check if the category is valid with this function

```
Validate::isLoadedObject($Category) //true or false
```

remember prestashop checks whether the values of the changes are valid

```
'name' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCatalogName', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
'link_rewrite' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isLinkRewrite', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
'description' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml'),
```

**isCatalogName, isLinkRewrite, isCleanHtml** these are controls insertion

Answer (score 0):

You must delete character not valid in link_rewrite. Delete punctuation marks, vowels with accents, brackets, ... 
In prestashop code there is a function to convert a string to link_rewrite.

Rarely does the array starts at 1... Change it:

$category->name[0]=...
$category->link_rewrite[0]=...

PD: The best way to manipulate data in prestashop is the Rest API

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply, can you provide me a little bit example code? I'm not a native speaker and not sure what you mean by that.